# Azure CLI Query to exclude certain Tag

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-cli, pulumi, infrastructure-as-code

In my specific case I have an Azure subscription with many resources and some are managed by Pulumi or Terraform. They were therefore tagged with "ManagedBy:Pulumi".

How do I use the CLI to get only the resources that do not have the tag "ManagedBy"?

Answer (score 0):

To get all resources in an Azure subscription that do not have a specific tag, you can use the following Azure CLI command:

```
az resource list --query "[?tags.['<tagName>'] == null]"
```

In my case:

```
az resource list --query "[?tags.['ManagedBy'] == null]"
```

Additionally you can filter the information you want as follows:

```
az resource list --query "[?tags.['ManagedBy'] == null].{type:type, name:name, id:id}"
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?tabs=concepts%2Cbash